# MIPS register does not assigns the 0XFA9C value to $a0 register

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to assign the 0xFA9C to $a0. But the Qtspim software shown an error whose screenshot is attached below. Thanks for your help.

[image: ERROR SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Well, just like the error says, the value you're trying to use is out of range for `addi`. You could try using the `li` pseudo-instruction instead, which should allow any 32-bit constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0xFA9C` is 64,156, which won't fit in the 16-bit signed immediate field of the `addi` instruction.

If you really want that number then load it as an immediate `li $t0, 0xFA9C` and the assembler will use two instructions to build that number.

If you intended that to be a negative number, e.g. -1380, then use decimal, or, (this works in MARS) pad it out to 32-bit hex with sign: `0xFFFFFA9C`, this tells the assembler it is a negative number, and, this number will fit in the 16-bit immediate of `addi`.

Comment: *and the assembler will use two instructions to build that number.* - or if it's smart, will use `ori $t0, $zero, 0xFA9C` to implement that `li`.  MIPS boolean instructions zero-extend their immediates, not sign-extend.  I checked and qtspim's assembler does actually know that trick.  (But it disassembles the resulting `3408fa9c` machine instruction as `ori $8, $0, -1380` which is only correct if you treat the immediate as `int16_t`, not 32-bit after zero extension :/)  Pretty sure GAS and clang also know to use `ori`, and probably MARS.

Comment: @PeterCordes. You're right, MARS does `ori $t0, $at, 0xFA9C`; however, MARS also takes `addi $a0, $a0, 0xFA9C`, and it generated `lui $at, 0x0` followed by `ori $a0, $a0, 0xFA9C` followed by `add $a0, $a0, $at` !

Comment: Yeah, MARS supports "extended" pseudo-instructions beyond what standard MIPS assemblers support.  i.e. it treats every instruction with an immediate as a potential pseudo-instruction.  The way it handles that is usually very dumb (inefficient), not optimizing for parts of the value being zero when expanding into patterns that can handle the general case.  e.g. `addi $a0, $zero, 0xFA9C` expands with the same pattern you described.

Comment: MARS doesn't AFAIK have an option to allow only "normal" pseudo-instructions.  If you disable "extended (pseudo) instructions and formats", that disables `li` as well.